# how to fix xamarin support jar file errors

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm currently attempting to fix build issues which occured once i tried to update some component. they told me i need to update some references. Oddly enough i now get these issues:

Now i'll just add some text so someone comming from google can find the potential answer as well:

error reading xamarin android.support embedded jar error in opening zip file.

[image: list of errors]

Does anyone know how to fix this? I've tried:

- Deleting and restoring nugetpackages, in hopes the nuget install script supplied these files,
- Uninstall+Install Support Package in Android SDK Manager
- Deleting files, in hope they are just temporary references and are pulled by xamarin if they are missing.

Neither one of those attempts worked out sadly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the reason of this issue was actually my own impatience. At some point after package updates i must have canceled the build process assuming that it got stuck, because it just wouldn't deploy. That resulted in incomplete jar files.

I fixed the issue by deleting the folders in AppData/Local/Xamarin which raised errors and that in turn made sure the build process redownloads the required files properly.

[image: output window]